# Dot Net Bar Button Click Area

Tags: button, dotnetbar

When I was using the button noticed that part of it is not working.

I wanted to know if it was normal? Or I need to change any settings to fix this.

[Image:» "Red range does not work"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO22W.png)

Note: The word "اضافة" within the red range Arabic and means "add" :-)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when using Symbol alongside the text! and when i remove the + symbol its work perfectly.

**But if anyone has solution to use symbol and text alongside without any conflict, Please Answer**